# a constructor having 2 parameters

Tags: java

In the code below, there are 2 different `Strings` in the constructor.  How do I call 2 separate methods `getName` and `getGender` so that their respective values `n` and `g` are read?

```
class Bachcha{

    String s1, s2;

    public Bachcha(String y, String z) {
        s1 = y;
        s2 = z;
    }

    String getName() {
        return s1;
    }

    String getGender() {
        return s2;
    }
}

class Details {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String n = System.console().readLine("enter name");
        String g = System.console().readLine("enter gender");
        Bachcha b = new Bachcha(n,g);
    }
}
```

Comment: `b.getName()` and `b.getGender()`

Comment: Maybe instead of naming your variables `s1`, `s2`, `y`, `z`, `n`, `g` and `b` give them descriptive names like:  `name`, `gender`, `bacha`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have created an instance of the class `Bachcha` in your main method, you can use that instance to access the methods.

```
String n = System.console().readLine("enter name");
String g = System.console().readLine("enter gender");
Bachcha b = new Bachcha(n, g);

b.getName();
b.getGender();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.println(b.getName());   
System.out.println(b.getGender());
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say your first step would be to make `getName()` and `getGender()` public.

Next name your properties accordingly `s1` becomes `name`, `s2` becomes `gender`.

Now you can call them as mentioned:

`b.getName()` and `b.getGender()`.